# React JS- Encode data of a config file and pass it to Header for api calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application, I am trying to do base 64 encoding for the user details so that I can pass these data in subsequent api calls. For example, if the logged in user is Rohn, the localStorage should have the encoded data for Rohn and likewise.  To do that,I have created a config file where I have saved all the user details like below-
config.json-

```
{
  "Rohn": {
                "age": "30",
                 "city": "Mexico",
                 "occupation": "service",
                },
   "Max": {
                "age": "32",
                 "city": "Colorado",
                 "occupation": "Business",
                },

  }
```

I want these data to be encoded to base 64 and passed in a Header for every request params. So to do that, I am including this config.json file in my LogIn Component like below-

```
      import React from "react";
            import Header from "./header";
            import PropTypes from "prop-types";
            import { connect } from "react-redux";
            import { createLogIn } from "../actions/action";

            const axios = require("axios");
            import config from "../config/config";

            class Login extends React.Component {
              constructor() {
                super();
                this.state = {
                  account : { user:'', password: ''},
                  authorizationError: false,
                  UserData: ""
                };
         let userDetails = this.state.UserData;
         localStorage.setItem("UserData", btoa(JSON.stringify(config[this.state.account.user])))

}

             componentDidMount () {
                var currentUserJwt = config[this.state.account.user];
                console.log(currentUserJwt);
              }


              handleAccountChange = ({ target: input}) => {
                const account = {...this.state.account}
                account[input.name] = input.value
                this.setState({ account})
              };


              handleLoginForm = (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                let postLoginData = {};

                // call to action
                this.props.dispatch(createLogIn(postLoginData));

                this.props.history.push('/intro');
                this.setState({ authorizationError: false });

              };

              render() {
                const {account} = this.state;
                return (
                  <div className="intro">
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleLoginForm}>
                    <div className="content container">
                      <div className="row">
                        <div className="logo-wrap">
                          <div className="logo intro-logo">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12">
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            autoFocus
                            placeholder="username"
                            name="user"
                            value={account.user}
                            onChange={this.handleAccountChange}
                          />
                          <input
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="password"
                            name="password"
                            value={account.password}
                            onChange={this.handleAccountChange}
                          />
                          <button className="lg-cta">
                            <span>Sign in</span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            }

            const mapStateToProps = state => ({
              logIn: state.logIn
            });

            export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);
```

I am trying to encode the data for a corresponding logged in user and send the encoded data in my api calls but the above approach is not working.I am not able to see the encoded data in my localStorage and hence not able to pass this in header for subsequent calls.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I am not able to see the encoded data for the user- Rohn and Max in my localStorage.

Comment: Besides the real question, you are aware that you add all that user config file to your output code, right? So, If I see this page, I will see/read all the contents of config file in your js source code

Comment: correct, but if I do console.log(config) , I see undefined.Am I not including the file correctly and reading?

Comment: To do that, I am doing config[this.state.account.user] so that the details related to the logged in user is picked up from the config file.

Comment: Your code is a mess. How should that even compile? I see multiple syntax errors. Like the constructor isn't closed.
The main problem here is that you update the localStorage just in the constructor (or so I guess, cause the constructor does not have an end point) with an empty string and then never again. So of course there is no data to encode.

Comment: That's a typo of course during copying my code from the editor :)